# Is it possible to refer to namespace from another module?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I want to refer to the namespace `ns("map")` from second server module `mod_btn_server2`. This module is nested in first server module `mod_btn_server1`. When I click 'Button 2' points should show up on a map but they didn't. Is it possible at all to refer to `"map"` from nested module?

Here's working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(mapboxer)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)


moduleServer <- function(id, module) {
    callModule(module, id)
}

# UI 1 #
mod_btn_UI1 <- function(id) {
    
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        actionButton(ns("btn1"), "Button 1"),
        mod_btn_UI2(ns("moduleServer2")),
        leafletOutput(ns("map"))
    )
}

# Server 1 #
mod_btn_server1 <- function(id){
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        
      ns <- NS(id)
      
      coords <- quakes %>%
        sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
            
      mod_btn_server2("moduleServer2", coords) # here is nested module2
         
        output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
          leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
            leaflet::addTiles() %>% 
            leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%
            leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
              data = coords,
              stroke = FALSE,
              radius = 6)
        })

        observeEvent(input$btn1, {
            leaflet::leafletProxy("map", data = coords) %>%
                leaflet::addCircles()
        })
             
    })
}

# Module 2 - UI #
mod_btn_UI2 <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
    actionButton(ns("btn2"), "Button 2"),
}

# Module 2 - server #
mod_btn_server2 <- function(id, dataMod){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
      leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
        leaflet::addTiles() %>% 
        leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%
        leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
          data = dataMod,
          stroke = TRUE,
          color = "red",
          radius = 6)
    })
    
# and here I refer to 'map' located in the first module
    observeEvent(input$btn2, {
      leaflet::leafletProxy("map", data = dataMod) %>%
        leaflet::addCircles()
    })
    
  })
}


# App #

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    tagList(
        mod_btn_UI1("test-btn"))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    mod_btn_server1("test-btn")
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How exactly is your setup/what do you want to achieve? In your second module `moduleServer2` you define a map in the server, but don't provide any UI, so it isn't shown. If you want to change something on the map defined in module `test-btn`, the canonical way would be to capture the button push as an output of module `moduleServer2` and use this as an input for `test-btn` where you perform the action. However, your button is already defined in `test-btn`, so I'm not sure what you exactly want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the canonical way would be to capture the button push as an output of module `moduleServer2` and use this as an input for `test-btn` where you perform the action.

However, if you want to mess around with the namespaces by yourself (not recommended), you can use the following solution. I had to adapt the `leafletProxy` function, because the normal implementation automatically adds the namespace of the calling module. This is what you don't want, because you want to use the namespace of a different module.

Now with code adapted to the edit:

```
library(shiny)
library(mapboxer)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

leafletProxy2 <- function (mapId, session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain(), 
                           data = NULL, deferUntilFlush = TRUE) 
{
  if (is.null(session)) {
    stop("leafletProxy must be called from the server function of a Shiny app")
  }
  structure(list(session = session, id = mapId, x = structure(list(), 
                                                              leafletData = data), deferUntilFlush = deferUntilFlush, 
                 dependencies = NULL), class = "leaflet_proxy")
}

# UI 1 #
mod_btn_UI1 <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("btn1"), "Button 1"),
    mod_btn_UI2(ns("moduleServer2")),
    leafletOutput(ns("map"))
  )
}

# Server 1 #
mod_btn_server1 <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    coords <- quakes %>%
      sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
    
       mod_btn_server2("moduleServer2", coords) # here is nested module2
    
    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
      leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
        leaflet::addTiles() %>% 
        leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%
        leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
          data = coords,
          stroke = FALSE,
          radius = 6)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$btn1, {
      leaflet::leafletProxy("map", data = coords) %>%
        leaflet::addCircles()
    })
    
  })
}

# Module 2 - UI #
mod_btn_UI2 <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("btn2"), "Button 2")
}

# Module 2 - server #
mod_btn_server2 <- function(id, dataMod, btn){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # and here I refer to 'map' located in the first module
    observeEvent(input$btn2, {
      leafletProxy2("test-btn-map", data = dataMod) %>%
        leaflet::addCircles(stroke = TRUE,
                            color = "red")
    })
    
  })
}


# App #

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tagList(
    mod_btn_UI1("test-btn"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mod_btn_server1("test-btn")
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is a more canonical form that works with the correct input/output of modules and doesn't mess with namespaces:

```
library(shiny)
library(mapboxer)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

# UI 1 #
mod_btn_UI1 <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("btn1"), "Button 1"),
    mod_btn_UI2(ns("moduleServer2")),
    leafletOutput(ns("map"))
  )
}

# Server 1 #
mod_btn_server1 <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    coords <- quakes %>%
      sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
    
    external_btn <- mod_btn_server2("moduleServer2", coords) # here is nested module2
    
    output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
      leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
        leaflet::addTiles() %>% 
        leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%
        leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
          data = coords,
          stroke = FALSE,
          radius = 6)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$btn1, {
      leaflet::leafletProxy("map", data = coords) %>%
        leaflet::addCircles()
    })
    
    observeEvent(external_btn(), {
      leaflet::leafletProxy("map", data = coords) %>%
        leaflet::addCircles(stroke = TRUE,
                            color = "red")
    })
    
  })
}

# Module 2 - UI #
mod_btn_UI2 <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("btn2"), "Button 2")
}

# Module 2 - server #
mod_btn_server2 <- function(id, dataMod){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    return(reactive(input$btn2))
    
  })
}


# App #

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tagList(
    mod_btn_UI1("test-btn"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mod_btn_server1("test-btn")
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I updated my main code, now it looks better. Basically, I want to show points on the map when I click the 'Button 2' in `module2`. Map is located in `module1`. I want to somehow render points on main map from within `module2`.

Comment: check my edit; should have been possible already with my previous version; now I've also adapted to colour

Comment: But please be aware that this solution is against the design principles of modules! I've added a more canonical solution

Comment: Ok, the main reason why I wanted to do this was dividing huge module into a few smaller ones. But now I need to think if it's better to have one huge module or few smaller since this solution is in fact against design princicples. If I can't reach `map` from within nested modules than I'll get back to one-module solution.

Comment: I mean you can and maybe for your use case it makes sense (then it's probably best to document it thoroughly), but the idea of modules is that all the communication that concerns elements created within a module should be done via arguments of this module

Comment: You are right, that's why I get back to my one-module solution, anyways thank you for interesting approach to my problem.